# What are the Moderation Policies for Comments and Chat?

Tags: discussion, comments, chat

The policy of each SE site is defined by its community, this is to solicit the opinion of Buddhism.SE on the use of chat and comments. So in the context of this site what are the Moderation Policies for Comments and Chat? Should we just have the same policy as the main StackOverflow (SO) site? What are relevant posts on this in SO? If we are to deviate from SO policy what would they be?

Comment: I think this should be ultimately linked to or covered in the welcome message.

Comment: I posted a new `proposed-faq` for comments -- [Commenting with minimal argument](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2409/254) -- would you like to review that, and say whether that's agreeable?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the need to be different to any other site

Answer (score 0):

> The policy of each SE site is defined by its community

Some policies are pre-defined by SE, and some defined by the community.

SE defines how to use the site:

- Use it for Q+A (not discussion)
- Don't misuse it, be nice, etc.
- Use Meta to discuss the site itself

The community defines what this community wants to use this site for:

- What's on-topic?

SE has policies about how to use comments (e.g. "not for extended discussion"), so when a comment isn't about the question or the answer then I tend to move the comment[s] to chat (because it has become an "extended discussion").

Generally a "chat room owner" can choose how to use a chat room.

- We've no special policy about this site's main chat room is used, and until now it hasn't been used much at all.
- Some other sites insist that chat in their chat room should be on-topic (e.g. about Buddhism or whatever the site topic is)
- Some other other sites use their chat room for friendly chat about anything -- e.g. the topic, the site, new posts on the site, each other, jokes, the weather, and so on.