# Where can I post on this site?

Tags: support

This site has various pages etc.

Where are the different places to post, and what is each one used for?

Answer (score 0):

### Main site

The main site is:

- https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/

This is for Question-and-Answer topics about Buddhism -- with a minimum of discussion, as described in [the tour](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/tour):

> [image]

The guidelines for posting on this site are slightly different than on other Stanch Exchange sites -- they're summarized here: [FAQ index (summary of site policies)](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2106/faq-index-summary-of-site-policies).

You probably don't need to read these usually -- simply use the site like most other people do!

### Meta site

The "Meta' site is this one i.e.:

- https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/

It's used for asking questions about the site (i.e. not about Buddhism), for discussing the guidelines for using the site, etc.

This site is for the "community" of user to discuss the site.

The moderators are "users" also, part of this community.

Generally, decisions are made by a majority of the community, and moderators help to publish and enact those decisions.

### Comments

You can post comments under questions and answers.

Please read [this Help topic](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) first -- including "When should I comment?" and "When *shouldn't* I comment?"

As a moderator I can tell you that most of the 'trouble' that needs 'moderating' comes from comments.

- If a couple of users want to discuss something, that's probably tolerated.
- If it turns into an argument, you can "flag" it for moderator to intervene.

There's slightly tedious list of guidelines here -- [Commenting with minimal argument](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2409/254) -- for posting a comment where it's not welcome. I suggest:

- Just one comment
- Politely
- About the topic, not the person

### Chat

The site has one or more chat rooms:

- https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=buddhism.stackexchange.com

One is open permanently, and temporary ones may be created when comments are "moved to chat".

The main chat room is hardly ever used so, if you post there, probably no-one will notice and reply?

### Moderators

The site's moderators can do a few things other users can't, including:

- Delete answers and comments
- Suspend a user account

If you see something wrong then you can "flag" it for moderator attention.

Note that an answer which is simply incorrect doesn't invite moderator attention -- you can "down-vote" that instead.

A moderator is more likely to intervene when:

- The answer is "hostile" to another user or a group of users
- The answer is off-topic e.g. not about "Buddhism"